# Replacing 1k resistor

Tags: resistors

I just bought new soldering station, when I turn it on the solder some thing burned inside the soldering station.
When I open the soldering station I found out that 1k resistor burned out.

Do I replace the 1k resistor with a resistor bigger than the 1k resistor?

or
What I should do?

this pictures for the bored and the burn resistor:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: This all looks bad quality work. I guess there's no evidence which shows 1)the burned resistor really was 1kOhm as printed on the PCB, 2)other components are still OK and 3) there's no wrong connection nor short circuit . Do as already suggested: try to get a working unit as a replacement. If the unit happens to be 40 years old (as it looks) getting a new can be difficult.

Comment: You can try putting a new 1k resistor in and hope for the best. But there are no guarantees because we don't know if the resistor just burned out in normal use or if some fault occurred elsewhere which caused the resistor to fail. You could also use a higher wattage resistor (for example a 1 W resistor). Good luck!

Comment: galaxy202 - Hi, This site is primarily focused on electronics *design* questions. Repair questions are only on-topic here when you supply *design-level* information e.g. schematics, and can do troubleshooting based on your measurements & tests, comparing them to the schematic. No schematic (as in this case) means readers don't know the original design and remote help is typically impractical. See the discussion: [Is asking how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478). Also beware of the electrocution risks when troubleshooting a mains-powered device.

Comment: That soldering station is so 'unusual' I can't even find it in a google search.   Return that piece of garbage, buy a HAKKO  i.e.  https://www.techni-tool.com/product/821SO890-FX-888D?mkwid=s&crid=522265622395&mp_kw=&mp_mt=b&pdv=c&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIirvb6t3l8wIVQyCtBh35NQIqEAAYAiAAEgKFpfD_BwE    These are the 'go to' for professional techs even if it looks like a toy.   I loaded our entire EE lab with them, folks love 'em.   Will last "forever".

Answer (score 1):

No. If you bought it new, return it for a working replacement. You shouldn’t have to repair a new item.

Comment: No warranty in it, but I get one and it has the same issue and I returned it to the store and the guy was nice enough to exchange it for me.